# Are there any JavaScript libraries for interacting with AOL's OSCAR protocol?

Tags: javascript, libraries, oscar-protocol

I know AOL provides a library for their Web AIM (or whatever its called) but I'm more interested in something I can use with something like v8cgi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting a client-side browser based solution, you'd have to create a proxy similar to how Meebo does this.  Otherwise, if you want to use something like [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) you'd be able to implement something using sockets.

In either case, you'd be hard pressed to find something already written to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm actually looking for something to run server-side with a library like v8cgi or narwhal.